# AWS Cost Management and Starting Multiple Instances based on tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to accomplish two things: 1. Power management, 2. The ability to start groups of servers based on a common tag or other feature.

**Power Management**: I did look at EC2 Scheduler for shutting down and starting up systems, the problem the development shop here is very flexible and might work at spurious times throughout the day or night.  Weekends are probably solid to shut down instances, but I am thinking CloudWatch alarms (maybe deployed through cloudformation) are a better solution; just shut down servers when they idle for a long enough period?

**Startup** is the one I'm still not sure of.  If everything is shut down via CloudWatch Alarms, then I need it to be easy for developers to bring up groups of servers without much trouble - so a simple command at most.  Is there a way to accomplish this based on tagging or something of that nature?

*Note* This is for the development environment, production will use different power management.

Thanks!

Comment: I think "capacity management" or "cost management" is probably a more appropriate term than "power management". Your terminology makes it sound like you are trying to save Amazon some money on their electric bill. For the "startup" portion of your question you could definitely write a small script using the AWS CLI or the AWS SDK of your language of choice to start up EC2 instances based on tags.

Comment: Noted, I changed edited the title to more accurately reflect the content of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common practice to stop/start Amazon EC2 instances based on a tag.

Here is an example in Python: [stopinator.py](https://github.com/ozbillwang/awscli.sh/blob/master/python.boto/spl46/stopinator.py)

Or, you could do it with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This command lists all instances with a given tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:Department,Values=HR --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId --output text
```

It can be inserted into a command to stop instances:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:cleanup,Values=ignore --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId --output text`
```

You could provide this as a script that your Developers could run when they want to stop/start instances. Or, you could write a small web-app that they access via a web page, that calls it on their behalf. (More secure, since you don't need to provide them with credentials.)

Comment: Awesome, this is kind of what  I was thinking, that helps alot!  How about creating this as lambda with sns activation?